# Packet analysis of IRC traffic

Tags: malware, wireshark, irc

I've been going through this malware traffic analysis [exercises](https://www.malware-traffic-analysis.net/2016/12/17/index.html) and part of the malicious traffic detected is IRC traffic over non-standard port 443. This is picked up by ET Snort rule [sid:2000348; rev:15](http://doc.emergingthreats.net/bin/view/Main/2000348)

The content of the rule is

> "JOIN "; nocase; depth:5; pcre:"/&|#|+|!/R"

How would I find this IRC JOIN command if I was to analyze the pcap using Wireshark? Is there a way that I can search the entire pcap for the string "JOIN"? Does Wireshark support using regex like the above Snort rule?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use a utility such as [ngrep(http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/usage.html)](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/usage.html) and pass it the .pcap file along with a regular expression.

EX: `ngrep -q -I file.pcap|grep -i user`

An example of this can be found on the web [HERE](https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/PCAP-Files-Are-Great-Arn-t-They--/)

Snippet from [trustwave.com](https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/PCAP-Files-Are-Great-Arn-t-They--/)

> 5) Search for text strings using ngrep
>
> This is useful to look for any specific string or regex you want e.g
>   look for "password", "card","username" etc....This will normally find
>   FTP, HTTP, or POP passwords as examples. Although this is a simple
>   example, ngrep can be used for complex regex's.
>
> ngrep -q -I file.pcap|grep -i user
>
> e.g
>
> ..........< TRUNCATED>..........
>
> en" id="secure_username" name="username" value="" />......
>
> ..........< TRUNCATED>..........
>
> 6) Find emails using ngrep ...

What regex to use:
I would encourage learning how to craft regular expressions if you haven't already as they are very useful.
(Not tested): `~JOIN`

EDIT: If you must use wireshark and not ngrep then I believe wireshark uses perl style regular expressions